# Using Ruby on Rails 5, what is an efficient way to check an array of ActiveRecord results for particular values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, permissions, access-control

In my application I have a Permissions table with columns `id, account_id, user_id, resource_type, resource_id, and role`. With Pundit, when a user attempts to access a particular resource, there are numerous possible Permissions records I need to check for in order for them to view/edit the page. I'm looking for the most efficient way to grab all the `Permissions.where(account_id: params[:account_id] && user_id: current_user.id)` and then cycle through them for all the various values that would grant access:

```
is_user_account_owner?
is_user_account_admin?
is_user_resource_moderator?
is_user_parent_resource_admin?
is_user_parent_resource_moderator?
is_user_parent_resource_viewer?
is_user_resource_viewer?
```

If any of these checks are true then the user can view the resource and the rest of the checks aren't needed. This is going to happen for every pageview so I would appreciate any advice how to make this efficient/scalable and especially would like some recommendations for how caching could be implemented here.

Comment: This really depends on how Permissions is implemented. Also you can't really using caching besides query caching here as the results are unique per client.

Comment: could you describe more what you think i’m missing in describing how I am implementing permissions? pretty basic; pundit per action looks up Permissions records and if certain values are present, access is granted/denied

Comment: Can you show your pundit implementation? You can't (and shouldn't) normally access `params[:account_id]` within a policy, so I'm unclear how you've written this.

Comment: And what is the "particular resource"? Anything belonging to an `Account`? How is the data modelled?

Comment: why would that be? what’s the difference if i pull in from params or just set an @account_id = params[:account_id] before the policy gets hit? i would show you my pundit code but i haven’t written it yet as i am still in the mind-mapping process of how i’m going to implement this before i get to coding it

Comment: see my other SO topic for data models: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49605418/with-rails-5-how-do-i-add-a-database-record-after-a-new-user-has-been-created the resources could be Accounts, Folders, or Posts. if a user is granted an Account permission that will apply to everything, Folder permission will apply to all Posts in that folder, Post permission is only for that one post.

Comment: @chrickso How are you going to set `@account_id`? Instance variables set in the controller class won't (without dodgy workarounds) be accessible in the policy class. Again, if you maybe show a minimal attempt at coding this, then I would have a better chance of understanding what you have in mind.

Comment: i have not done this yet but my initial thought was that i would have access to the params inside of the policies. if you are saying otherwise then I am open to suggestions how to get it there. can i not just add it to the initialize and send it in through the controller with authorize? i’m not opposed to attempting some code to provide but i’m at my day job atm and was hoping to get an idea of how to tackle this for when i get home tonight.

Comment: I strongly suggest you make a serious attempt at this yourself, then update the question with what you have tried so far.

Comment: @TomLord done. posted the results of my attempt in an answer below. would love to hear your feedback.

Comment: What you´re doing actually looks very much like [Rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify)

Answer (score 0):

I got this working how I wanted but not by cycling through query results like my question asks for.

Because my app has a multi-tenant setup, it is essential that Pundit has access to the account_id that is specified in the Params so that I can do Permission checks in places like my Post#index when there may be no records to pass to pundit to obtain the account_id from.

Much to [Tom Lord](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1954610/tom-lord)'s dismay, I'm sure, I have employed Pundits [additional context](https://github.com/varvet/pundit#additional-context) feature to always pass in my @account variable that gets set on every request from the params[:account_id], with the current_user context:

application_controller.rb:

```
def pundit_user
  UserContext.new(current_user, @account)
end
```

policies/user_context.rb:

```
class UserContext
  attr_reader :user, :account

  def initialize(user, account)
    @user = user
    @account = account
  end
end
```

policies/application_policy.rb:

```
class ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :request_account, :user, :record

  def initialize(user_context, record)
    @user = user_context.user
    @account = user_context.account
    @record = record
  end

...
```

So now in my individual policies, I can perform the checks I wanted to determine if current_user has any of the Permission records that would grant access to the action and all in one query:

policies/note_policy.rb:

```
class NotePolicy < ApplicationPolicy

def index?
    Permission.where({account_id: @account, user_id: user.id}) \
    .where({resource: 'Account', role: :owner}) \
    .or(Permission.where({account_id: @account, user_id: user.id}) \
        .where({resource: 'Account', role: :admin})) \
    .exists?
  end

  def show?
    Permission.where({account_id: record.account_id, user_id: user.id}) \
    .where({resource: 'Account', role: :owner}) \
    .or(Permission.where({account_id: record.account_id, user_id: user.id}) \
        .where({resource: 'Account', role: :admin})) \
    .or(Permission.where({account_id: record.account_id, user_id: user.id}) \
        .where({resource: 'Note', role: :viewer})) \
    .exists?
  end
```

and the calls to authorize in notes_controller.rb:

```
  def index
    authorize Note
    @notes = @account.notes.all
  end


  def show
    @note = @account.notes.find(params[:id])
    authorize @note
  end
```

Not the cleanest approach, I'm sure, but it works. If any glaring security concerns, I would be happy to hear feedback.

Comment: Not so much to *my* dismay, but more to the author of Pundit who very [clearly wrote in that link](https://github.com/varvet/pundit#additional-context) that this is probably not the best way to model it...

Comment: And indeed, how are you actually calling this policy authorisation **in the controller**? That line of code, which is missing from your answer above, is the crucial reason why you should see no reason to use Pundit in this way.

Comment: In the index action, your"admin" logic makes no sense -- if such a permission exists, then **everyone** can perform the action, and if no such record exists then the logic is redundant. And either way, crucially, how are you **scoping** the response? This is what Pundit is supposed to be used for here, but you've shown no code for it.

Comment: As for the `show?` action, again your logic is faulty. I'd advise you to check what SQL is actually being generated and write some unit tests to see who is actually allowed to view the resource. At least in this case, however, you appear to be trying to use Pundit properly (and unsuprisingly, here you don't need a spurious `@account` variable!)

Comment: updated to show my latest queries (already had discovered the query error you describe) and the controller's call to authorize is now shown. the response is scoped via the accounts.notes relations.

Comment: you are right in that the "@account" variable is not needed for show but it is needed for anywhere that the record does not contain it's own relation to the account_id (like index). i suppose i could pass in a query for "@account.notes.first" just to pull out the account_id but i kindof like my way better and have not heard any actual reasons not to do it my way other than "its not the best way".

Comment: The `index` action could just be calling [`policy_scope(Note.where(account_id: params[:account_id])`](https://github.com/varvet/pundit#scopes) (i.e. there is no need to `authorize` at all in an `index` action, ax explained in the Pundit README), and the `show` action can call `authorize(Notes.find(params[:id])`. In both cases, there is no need for passing additional context to the pundit class. And by using `policy_scope`, you're declaring permissions in the policy rather than relying on additional scope in the controller.

Comment: From a security standpoint, your updated code looks OK now - but it's still quite messy (for the above reasons); you're not yet using the design patterns intended by Pundit to their potential.